# Execution flow in shell script

Tags: java, shell, scripting

I have below code in my entry point script for my java program. I am doing some post processing logic for istio process which is running along with my java application. This is after my main thread of java application stops running. Does the shell script wait for java process to complete before executing next line or do I need to conditionally check if java process has terminated?

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
set +x
   
    JVM_OPTS="-XX:+UseG1GC"

    # Application start-up JVM args
    START_CMD="java ${JVM_OPTS} ${JVM_ARGS} -jar ${1}"
    $START_CMD
    # will flow execution pause here till java process completes?
    
    #post processing logic after main java thread finishes
    x=$(echo $?)
    #Do I need to conditionally check for value of x before executing below line?
    curl -fsI -X POST http://localhost:15000/quitquitquit
    exit $x
```

Comment: *Does the shell script wait for java process to complete before executing next line* Yes. But if you need to *only* execute the curl command after a *successful* Java exit, then you do need to check it, or do `$START_CMD && curl ...` You've done `set -e` so that would happen anyway but it's probably good to get into a good habit ;)

Comment: @g00se I need to run it in all cases if java process runs successfully or not. I guess I can skip the condition in that case.

Comment: Yes you can skip it